# List template with Lookup columns not working

Tags: infopath

I have a list with lookup columns and I have used infopath to implement cascading drop down for the lookup columns . Now I created this list as a template in order to re use the list in another site under same site collection.  I have edited the list template for replacing the lookup column list Guids with Look up column list names in order to use in another sites templates . after this when I add the list and clicked on the new item . it is throwing error

Comment: Are you including content(existing items) in your list template? Do you have the list from where you are using lookup on the new site?

Comment: I am not including content. I am having the look up lists in the new site , earlier when I used the same List template with out infopath  and with java script for getting cascading drop downs then it worked . but I need to replace JS cascading drop downs with infopath cascading drop downs . may be i need to save the infopath form and replace url in manifest file to work with any site. but I am not sure how do I replace the url to work with any site .

Comment: Check that the lookup columns are properly connected from the list settings. In some cases you need to reconnect the columns.